# TCP clients connecting outside of defined port range

Tags: linux, ip, tcp

A TCP server runs on an Ubuntu 18.04 box.

Here's the local port range configuration on this box:

```
blah@blah:~# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 32768    60999
```

The issue is that for some clients which connect to the TCP server the allocated port are sometimes out of this range, e.g. last week:

```
2010
2288
11970
11971
14114
14115
15781
17609
```

It always occurs with malicious clients (according to AbuseIPDB).

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range` only controls the "ephemeral" ports a socket will be bound to when `connect()` or `listen()` is called on it without it having been bound before, or when `bind()` is called with a port = 0.

It will not enforce a range of ports any *external* clients can use when connecting to the server -- you could use iptables or other kind of firewall for that, though such an endeavour will be completely pointless.

Also, that `ip_local_port_range` sysctl will not prevent explicitly `bind()`ing a socket to any free port >= 1024 (either inside or outside the range) before calling `connect()` on it.

Sometimes you want to have both an ipv4 and ipv6 socket bound to the same port, and as there's no API for that, you let the kernel choose a port for the ipv6 socket with `bind(port = 0)`, then call `getsockname()` and try to bind the ipv4 socket to the same port, and rinse/repeat the procedure until the kernel picks a port that's free for both ipv4 and ipv6. That's something ssh servers have to do when they're requested to do a remote forwarding with `-R`, but the port argument is 0.

Comment: I was indeed logging the remote port instead of the local port, thanks.